# Magento admin nav not working - not loading prototype.js correctly

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7

I searched for an answer and found that this is because the prototype.js is not being called successfully, I checked my source, and for some reason magento is trying to load it from the media folder?

My stage areas that have copies of the store are working fine, and I can't find anything that fixes this.

Any idea why Magento is looking in the wrong place? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Developer Settings -> Javascript Settings -> Merge JavaScript Files and set it to "no".